# How to get a QImage POINTER from model/view

Tags: c++, qt, qimage

How can I get the QImage * that I stored in a model?

This is where my image manager stores the image:

```
QImage * tmpImage = new QImage(sFileNames.at(i));

//Add image to the model view
QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem();            
item->setData(*tmpImage, Qt::DecorationRole);
ImageModel->appendRow(item);
```

Now in another class, I want to access the selection in the view and get the pointer. Here's what I have so far:

```
void NodeEditor::on_set_input_image_clicked()
{
    QModelIndex index = ui->image_list_view->currentIndex();
    QVariant data = ui->image_list_view->model()->data(index);

    //QImage * tmpImg = data.value<QImage*>(); //Returns compilation error
    //pImageMap->SetInputImage(pTmpImg);
}
```

Comment: `QImage tmpImg = data.value<QImage>();` Also, you want `data(index, Qt::DecorationRole)`

Comment: Is there a way to get a pointer though? I don't want to create a new image.

Comment: QImage is passed by copy, you do not pass a pointer to it so you will always get a copy

Comment: Oh yeah I just noticed on the setData I'm not actually passing the pointer. So once I edit that, should that do the trick?

Comment: Qt uses reference-counted sharing for most its data structures. `QImage` is cheap to copy - it's similar to a `shared_ptr<QImageImpl>`, where `QImageImpl` is some internal class that really manages the image data. Just treat `QImage` as a value class - that's how idiomatic Qt works.

Comment: Just to add to the comments by @IgorTandetnik, you might want to look at [implicit sharing in `Qt`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html).

Answer (score 0):

How? By not using a pointer to start with :)

Modern C++'s primary raison d'être is to enable programming without having to worry about manual memory management. All you have to do is to use a `QImage` value. They are cheap to copy, and the memory is then managed for you by the compiler and the image implementation. That's all.

To extract the `QImage` - and not a pointer to it - you'd then write:

```
auto const role = Qt::DecorationRole;
auto model = ui->image_list_view->model();
auto const image = model->data(index, role).value<QImage>();
```